# Modifying paragraph display in tableofcontents causes paragraph title to disappear

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I modified the way paragraphs are displayed in the **table of contents**, but this caused the title of the paragraphs to disappear in the pdf.

Below is the LateX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{paragraph}{\S \hspace{2pt}{\footnotesize #1}}
}
\makeatother

%---------------------
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\section{Abstract}

\subsection{TEST 1}

\subsubsection{SUBTEST 1}

\paragraph{paragraph 1}

\paragraph{paragraph 2}


\end{document}
%---------------------
```

And here is the resulting pdf document obtained:

[image: Resulting Document]

Does someone has an explanation for this? Is there a specific documentation I can refer to for this matter?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your redefinition of `\paragraph` changed of course the meaning of `\paragraph` as sectioning unit and you killed the code that is meant for the paragraph title (and number) in the text. The `\addcontentsline` does exactly what it is meant for and what its name indicates, but it has nothing to do with the display of paragraph titles in the text. In short: Your approach is not useful, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{paragraph}{\S \hspace{2pt}{\footnotesize #1}}
}
```

will destroy the original `\paragraph` coding (the call to `\@startsection{paragraph}{...}`) and therewith the display of headings -- neither will it be numbered nor a counter stepped etc -- there is nothing display other than the contentsline added to the ToC, which is requested, however.

Since paragraphs shall be unnumbered apparently, the `\S` symbol can be placed inside `\cftparafont` if `tocloft` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\newcommand{\paragraphsymbol}{\S}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\renewcommand{\cftparafont}{\paragraphsymbol~\footnotesize}

%---------------------
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\section{Abstract}

\subsection{TEST 1}

\subsubsection{SUBTEST 1}

\paragraph{paragraph 1}

\paragraph{paragraph 2}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @christian-hupfer! It works just fine! Would you know if the same result could be obtained without using the ```tocloft``` package?

Comment: @Goûtay: Yes, but requires severe hacking... believe me, `tocloft` is the better way to go here!

Comment: Okay. Nevermind then. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Goûtay: The correct way to say 'thank you' is to accept the answer ;-)